# Unix Shell scripting - calculating last week date based on given date

Tags: shell

Need a help in unix shell script in calculating date.

I will be getting date value (eg: 20150908) as parameter, now inside the script i need to calculate 7 days ago date (20150908 -7).

something like below:
date=20150908 
lastweek_date=20150908 - 7  ---> this should output as 20150901

Could someone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With GNU date, we can subtract one week:

```
$ date -d "20150908 - 1 week" '+%Y%m%d'
20150901
```

Alternatively, we could subtract 7 days:

```
$ date -d "20150908 - 7 days" '+%Y%m%d'
20150901
```

And, to show that this works over month boundaries:

```
$ date -d "20150901 - 1 week" '+%Y%m%d'
20150825
```

This solution is *not* OSX/BSD compatible.

Answer (score -1):

A week is `604800` seconds long so to get the number of seconds since the epoch in a portable and POSIX compliant fashion and use it to compute the date 1 week ago do as follows:

```
PRESENT=$( date +%s )

WEEKAGO=$(( PRESENT - 604800 ))

printf "%s\n" "$WEEKAGO"
```